# setVisibility function in android studio studio java parameters

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-view

I have checked the android docs for `setVisibility()`. It shows that

```
setVisibility(int value)
```

So as far as I know it means that `setVisibility()` accepts an integer value as input. But in one of the java codes, I found that it was written as

```
setVisibility(view.Visible)
```

This means it takes a view type as input. But how's that possible. I can't understand the logic behind this. Can anyone help in sort out this?

Comment: If you just do Ctrl+B you will see that View.Visible refers to int value      /**
     * This view is visible.
     * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
     * android:visibility}.
     */
    public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;

Comment: are you working with kotlin?

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh Nop Java. Thanks anyway I got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it accept the integer value. But internally it have defined TypeDef of visibility options with values of VISIBLE, INVISIBLE and GONE. All three options have their int value defined internally (you don't have to worry about it).

So, whenever you pass View.Visible it takes the internal int value of that.

And one thing, it have defined TypeDef so you can pass value as integer same as they have internally, but you can't pass another values.

Those are the int value of that all options:

```
VISIBLE = 0x00000000
INVISIBLE = 0x00000004
GONE = 0x00000008
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `int` argument of `setVisibility()` method

```
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

There is inbuilt int of this Gone , invisible etc...

```
    public static final int GONE = 8;
    public static final int INVISIBLE = 4;
    public static final int VISIBLE = 0;
```